# JQuery check the file size from inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have these Jquery code where the function will check the file extension and the file size from the input file. The checking for the file extension works fine, but the file size checking is not working, can you guys help me with this problem?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/* Some other code 

*/

var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'pdf'];    
    var status = false;

    function checkFile(fileinput){
        if ($.inArray(fileinput.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
            alert("Tolong upload file dengan extensi: " + fileExtension.join(', '));
            fileinput.value = "";
            return status = false;
        }

        if (fileinput[0].size > 1048576) {
            alert("The maximum file size is 1 mb");
            fileinput.value = "";
            return status = false;
        }

        else {
            return status = true;
        }
    }

    $('#btn_IdentitasKTP\\/Paspor').on('click', function () {
        $('#file_IdentitasKTP\\/Paspor').trigger('click')
    });

    $('#file_IdentitasKTP\\/Paspor').change(function () {

        var fileinput = $('#file_IdentitasKTP\\/Paspor').val();

        checkFile(fileinput);

        if (status == true) {
            var file_name = this.value.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
            $('#text_IdentitasKTP\\/Paspor').val(file_name);
            status = false;
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('#file_IdentitasKTP\\/Paspor').change(function () {
    var fileinput = this.files;
    ...
```

you can check file size by :

```
console.log(fileinput[0].size)
```

Comment: using this one works for the size checking, but now I got an error in checking the file extension

error: fileinput.split is not a function

Comment: The OP is already doing this, see this line in their code: `if (fileinput[0].size > 1048576) {`

Comment: @melonsoda20 Your question says the *exact* opposite: `The checking for the file extension works fine, but the file size checking is not working`. Please be clear about what the problem is

Comment: @Rory McCrossan It's the opposite when I changed my code using El Alami Anas suggestion(changing my var fileinput = $('#file_IdentitasKTP\\/Paspor').val();  to  var fileinput = this.files;). In the OP the problem is in the file size checking. But after using El Alami Anas answer, the problem becomes in checking the file extension

Comment: @melonsoda20 you can get `filename` from `fileinput[0].name`, even if you want extra information just try `console.log(fileinput)` you'll know them all =). here mozilla document : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: @El Alami Anas thank you for the help, I see what you mean now. I've altered my code based on your answer. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For example to upload image by AJAX. You will simply write this code. You will size with object. it will return size of that object.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#uploadimage").on('submit', (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    formdata = new FormData(this);
    if (formdata[0].size = < 1000) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "PHp File name path", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST", // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: formdata, // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false, // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false, // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData: false, // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data) // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
          $('#loading').hide();
          $("#message").html(data);
        }

      });
    } else {
      alert("You can not Upload this file Please resize this image.")
    }
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated code for this question.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
/* Some other code 

*/

var fileExtension = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'pdf'];    
    var status = false;

    function checkFile(fileinput){
        if ($.inArray(fileinput[0].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
            alert("Tolong upload file dengan extensi: " + fileExtension.join(', '));
            fileinput.value = "";
            return status = false;
        }

        if (fileinput[0].size > 1048576) {
            alert("Tolong upload file dengan ukuran dibawah 1mb");
            fileinput.value = "";
            return status = false;
        }

        else {
            return status = true;
        }
    }

    $('#btn_IdentitasKTP\\/Paspor').on('click', function () {
        $('#file_IdentitasKTP\\/Paspor').trigger('click')
    });

    $('#file_IdentitasKTP\\/Paspor').change(function () {
        var fileinput = this.files;

        checkFile(fileinput);

        if (status == true) {
            var file_name = this.value.replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
            $('#text_IdentitasKTP\\/Paspor').val(file_name);
            status = false;
        }

    });
});
```